# Having trouble calling aspx.cs method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

My aspx page contains a drop down mwnu with some values. I would like to call my `loadInstances()` method in the related aspx.cs page when a change is detected in the drop down. I've got an event listener attached to the menu like this:

```
$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_DropDownListCounter").change(function () {
    console.log("I've been hit!");
    <%loadInstances();%>;
});
```

My aspx.cs method looks like this:

```
public void loadInstances()
{
    foreach (string dataInfo in DataHelper.getInfo())
    {
        ListItem item = new ListItem(dataInfo, dataInfo);
        ListBoxData.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Where `ListBoxData` is a ListBox in my aspx page which I would like to be populated on change of the dropdown. I can confirm that the event listener is working as I've got the "I've been hit!" appearing in my console. However the `loadInstances()` method isn't being called. Have I missing a step to call my aspx.cs method from my aspx page?

Comment: Use ajax and webmethods. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/calling-server-side-function-from-javascript-in-Asp-Net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please modify your code like this:-

```
$("#<%=DropDownListCounter.ClientID%>").change(function () {
    console.log("I've been hit!");
    "<%=loadInstances()%>";        
});
```

But the operation you are doing for that you need to add `AutoPostBack="true"` in `DropDownList` then this script will work.
if you don't want `AutoPostBack` you can use `Ajax` or `UpdatePanel`

Comment: This won't work because my loadInstances() is void and doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Novastorm add `AutoPostBack="true"` in your `DropDownList` like this `<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListCounter" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ></asp:DropDownList>`

Comment: Absolutely right, that was my bad I didn't add the `AutoPostBack="true"` - many thanks! :)